# Not able to launch Gallery from Android Instant app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-instant-apps

I created an app which picks up images from images folder in emulator and displays selected image in my layout of application. When I converted my app to instant app, the same code that picks up images from image folder throws exception. I used runtime permissions READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

My code:

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 234;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Exception thrown:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start activity Intent { 
          act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=*/* }
```

Code for runtime permissions:

```
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 112;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public boolean checkPermission()
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Denied...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
                    return  true;
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: So how did you deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant Apps are blocked from accessing some features that regular Android apps can access. The exception:

`java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start activity Intent...`

Means you have found one such feature. In this case it is [`Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) which is not currently allowed. Support for additional features such as this may be introduced over time.

In addition, Instant Apps do not have access to read or write from external storage so requesting access to [`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) will also not work or throw an exception. See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html#available-permissions) for a list of permissions that are supported by Instant Apps.

Comment: When I try to launch CAMERA with permission ,instant app displays Toast as "No Camera" in Android 7.1 emulator.How to enable Camera through Instant app ?

Comment: Camera should work. Can you try starting the system camera app and ensure the emulator you setup can emulate a camera? If not you may need to go into the emulator settings and ensure camera emulation is on.